# How to retrieve specific rows from SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I was wondering is there a way to retrieve, for example, 2nd and 5th row from SQL table that contains 100 rows?

I saw some solutions with `WHERE` clause but they all assume that the column on which `WHERE` clause is applied is linear, starting at 1.

Is there other way to query a SQL Server table for a specific rows in case table doesn't have a column whose values start at 1?

P.S. - I know for a solution with temporary tables, where you copy your select statement output and add a linear column to the table. I am using T-SQL

Comment: what is your condition for sql data retrieval

Comment: What kind of SQL are you using? MySQL, MSSQL, Postgres, etc?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? Rownum-functionalities are now available in most systems, but are very much still different defined as per system.

Comment: @UpvoteMarkAnswer - my condition? I have to return rows at spot 5,6 or 7

Comment: @kmae - MAnagment Studio 2012

Comment: if your id is unique the use "select * from tablename where (id=5) and (id=6) and (id=7)"

Comment: @UpvoteMarkAnswer - Yes but mj ID column is like 12298, 11667 etc for 5,6 and 7 rows

Comment: you mean there is nothing different to query about..

Comment: There is no such thing as the "2nd" row in a relational table. You need to have some kind of "ordering criteria" do be able to identify the "2nd" row.

Comment: simply use row_number funtion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnName ASC) AS rownumber
    FROM TableName
)  as temptablename
WHERE rownumber IN (2,5)
```

Answer (score 5):

With SQL Server:

```
; WITH Base AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) RN FROM YourTable
)

SELECT *
    FROM Base WHERE RN IN (2, 5)
```

The `id` that you'll have to replace with your primary key or your ordering, `YourTable` that is your table.

It's a CTE (Common Table Expression) so it isn't a temporary table. It's something that will be expanded together with your query.

Comment: Sorry, I guess you didn't understand, I don't have a column with linear increment starting from 1.

Comment: @AntunTun Have I told you you need a column with linear increment? :-)

Comment: If you have the `top` clause, you need an additional order by, or there's no guarantee you'll get rows 2 and 5.

Comment: @podiluska You are probably right... While I always get the rows ordered by the `ROW_NUMBER()` if I only use it, it's probably a side-effect, not something certain.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on SQL Server 2005 or above, you could use `Row_Number()` function. Ex:

```
;With CTE as (
    select col1, ..., row_number() over (order by yourOrderingCol) rn
    from yourTable
)
select col1,...
from cte
where rn in (2,5)
```

Please note that `yourOrderingCol` will decide the value of row number (i.e. `rn`).

Answer (score 2):

There is no 2nd or 5th row in the table.

There is only the 2nd or 5th result in a resultset that you return, as determined by the order you specify in that query.

Comment: I know, I was thinking 2nd by nonlinear primary key column